# alias for count in Pyspark

Tags: count, pyspark, alias

I am new to Pyspark. I am trying to use alias for count function. For some reason if I use `agg` in front of `count` then `alias` is working but if I am not aggregating then the `alias` is giving me error.

```
.(count("firstName").alias("cnt"))
```

doesn't work;

```
.agg(count("firstName").alias("cnt"))
```

works.

I wanted to understand the issue with the 1st query.

Comment: The first method is [`pyspark.sql.GroupedData.count()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.count), which *Counts the number of records for each group.* It does not return a [`pyspark.sql.Column`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column) and [`alias`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.alias) is a `Column` function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try this:

```
.count().withColumnRenamed("count","cnt")
```

we cannot alias count function directly